# jQGrid how add columns in groupText

Tags: jqgrid

I have grid where i want to group by multiple columns but jqgrid support only single column grouping, than I thought that i may groupt by one column and display all the rest columns using `groupText : ['<b>{0} - {column1} {column2} {column3} {column4}</b>']`, but looks like it is problem as well, couldn't find how to do that, may be some one come across that?

this doc http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping saying that i may use only `{0}` which means that the group value name and `{1}` which meant the the total cont of this group.

My data looking like that:

```
Id | Group | Column1     | Column2 |Column3 | Column4  Name
1  | 1     | 02-dec-2003 | Good    | Rain   | 1000   | Name1
2  | 1     | 02-dec-2003 | Good    | Rain   | 1000   | Name2
3  | 2     | 01-dec-2004 | Bad     | Sun    | 1000   | Name3
4  | 2     | 01-dec-2004 | Bad     | Sun    | 1000   | Name4
5  | 2     | 01-dec-2004 | Bad     | Sun    | 1000   | Name5
```

I was thinking group by Group and add `Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4` in to grouping text.

Any ideas how i can do that or something similar?

Also i can combine my Columns in to one to produce something like that:

```
Id | Group                       | Name
1  | 1 02-dec-2003 Good Rain 1000| Name1
2  | 1 02-dec-2003 Good Rain 1000| Name2
3  | 2 01-dec-2004 Bad Sun 1000  | Name3
4  | 2 01-dec-2004 Bad Sun 1000  | Name4
5  | 2 01-dec-2004 Bad Sun 1000  | Name5
```

But I am thinking it will be slow to group by such long strings because grouping will be slow in such case.

Comment: did you solve that, @Joper ? I just got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar problem.  I'd like to group by multiple columns so that the collapsed row shows the grouped data once and uncollapsing it shows the detail.